# Database Design Example, is it correct?

Tags: database-design

I wanted to use a family as an example but i forgot that parents have 2 objects(Husband and Wife) to Children so it added unnecessary work so i just opted for an easier one which is a story database.

I wanted to finally clear my confusion, all my research just leads to me doubting myself so this is when a third party advice comes in as a reassurance as you all probably are more experienced than i am in this field so i am deferential to your opinions.

Here is a simple layout: All primary key id are auto-increment

**First Design**
[image]

So in the above Tables, in my limited understanding, its a 1 to many relationship as in 1 story to many chapters.

**Second Design**
[image]

Did i do right in my second design or did i misunderstand something and made things more complicated?

If my second design is correct, then how do i suppose to do CRUD operations on all three tables?

Say for example: If you create a story then you also have to atleast create 1 chapter then you can add more later on.

> -> create story row in story table(insert)
>
> -> create chapter row in chapter table(insert)
>
> -> create story_chapter row in story_chapter table(insert)

Is the above procedure correct? Since in story_chapter table both story_id and chapter_id are Foreign keys so both cannot be null when created thus i have to first create the story row then the chapter row then can i create the row for the middleman? Is story_chapter table more dependent upon chapter table? if a chapter doesn't exist(if a user deleted all chapters after creating) then i would also have to delete the rows in the story_chapter relating to the chapters deleted thus a story row can exist but the other two is not a must, but if a chapter does exist then story and story_chapter must also exist?

P.S. i'll be using this as my basis for all other table designs and operations ill have later on.

Edit:

User to story Table relation(i based my story-chapter relationship based on this).

1 user/author may have many Stories.

[User to Story](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xazm8.png)

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. Use edit functions to inline, not link, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Give credit to what you quote.

Comment: Hi. Time to read a book on information modeling, the relational model & database design. Re 1st why do you need chapter id when you have story & chapter number? Yes the 2nd design is unnecessarily complicated but since you don't reference any design method & tell us how you followed it to come up with these designs there's nothing to call correct or incorrect & an explanation is the same as writing a textbook--your question is currently too broad.

Comment: I merely used the chapter number to allocate an integer for each chapter on which chapter comes first. For example: chapter 1: Beginning, chapter 2[chapter_number]: War[Title].

Doesn't have any other function than to order the chapters.

I'm major on web development, trying to do a project by myself is complicated and unorganized as heck since i have to do everything and little changes to the db affects how i code in the backend and frontend. I also came to realize how important front-end design is just as much as backend. At this point i'm just going in circles.

Comment: So a story & a chapter number identify a chapter of a book, ie a chapter (of a story). So chapter ids (& story-chapter ids) are redundant. Anyway, as I say, you need a modeling/design textbook. Dozens are free on the web in pdf, also academic course slides & videos (eg at stanford.edu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, any story has many chapters, but each chapter is in only one story.

In your second example, any story has many chapters and each chapter can be in every story. It means that you can have the following:

1. Lord of the rings

   1.1 LOTR - Chapter 1

   1.2 LOTR - Chapter 2
2. 50 Shades of Grey

   2.1 50 Shades of Grey - Chapter 1

   1.2 LOTR - Chapter 2

---

```
|-----------------------| |------------------------| |----------------------------|
|     story_chapter     | |         story          | |          chapter           |
|-----------------------| |------------------------| |----------------------------|
| story_id | chapter_id | | story_id | story_title | | chapter_id | chapter_title |
|     1    |     1      | |     1    |    LOTR     | |     1      |   Chapter 1   |
|     1    |     2      | |     2    | 50 Shades...| |     2      |   Chapter 2   |
|     2    |     3      | |------------------------| |     3      |   Chapter 1   |
|     2    |     2      |                            |----------------------------|
|-----------------------|
```

I don't think it's a good idea to do like that and you should stick with the first example.

About your questions about the way you can work with the second example:

- Your insert procedure is right, and you can create chapter before story, it doesn't matter in this design
- Note that a foreign key may be NULLABLE (it may depends on your RDBMS), so be careful when you create your table
- In this design, you have to decide wether you want to remove chapters of other stories (remember, they are linked to many stories) when you delete one story or not. If not, you can just delete the `story_chapter` row and the link between a chapter and a story will vanish with it, but not the rows

  - Based on the first design, yes, you should delete orphan chapters or just disable the deletion of story with chapters linked to it

Comment: In my second design.

Story has many chapter. There are 3 integers in the story_chapter table.

First is the Primary key which is auto increment, used this to reference the rows on the table.

And there are 2 foreign keys to point to the story and chapter table.

So if LoTR is story_id = 1, then the first chapter of LoTR is chapter_id = 1, 50 shades is story_id = 2, 50shades chapter 1 is chapter_id = 2.

Then it would look just like this:
1 1 1(LoTR chapter 1)
2 2 2(50 shades chapter 2)

Comment: Or let's say the LoTR chapter 1 is story_chapter_id = 2 in story_chapter table then it would still look like this: 1 2 2, 2 1 1 - it will still point to the correct chapters and story. Or am i misudnerstanding your point?

Comment: In the second design, nothing stop the fact that you may have 1-1-1, 1-2-2, 2-1-1, 2-2-2. Or, you could use a trigger to avoid the usage of a new pair involving a new story_id with an already used chapter_id, but it would result in the same as the first example with no benefits and more complexity.

Comment: story_chapter_id shouldn't be repeating as it is auto increment.
Story_id and chapter_id too are auto incremented. The only rows i can see repeating are the story_id as they have many chapters. so, 1-1-1, 2-1-2, 3-1-3, 4-1-4. something like that.

Comment: I edited my response and added a table example so you can figure out what I am trying to explain. Your auto increments are in the `story` and `chapter` table, but your table `story_chapter` is a reference table, so you can put whatever IDs you want while it is present in the referenced tables. It may produce business logic failure.

Comment: I edited my question and added the user to story table in the end of it as it is related to my question, in a sense i first implemented it onto the user to story tables before i did the story to chapters table.

Does the same problem exist for it?

Comment: I tried to write this down on a bond paper and i can't understand how every chapter can be in any story.

Let me recap: All Primary keys of the 3 tables have Auto-Increment property meaning no primary key can be duplicated, the database itself will send out an error if you try to insert a value for the ID(whenever i insert rows i don't include the primary key columns as they are automatically filled in by the database - i use phpmyadmin).

The only thing duplicating in my paper is the story id which is understandable as a single story can have many chapter.

Comment: I went over your example: The 4th row in the story_chapter table in your example should not exist as there are only 3 rows in the chapter table. Whenever i add a chapter onto an existing story, i also send the story_id of the current story to the functions so i would know what story the chapter being inserted belongs to.

The problem you state can only happen, If i purposefully try to do it. Otherwise the problem would not occur.

Comment: Again, same problem with your new table. If you want just one author per story, then you should make a one to many relationship. But if you want one or more authors per story, you can then make a many to many relationship. In the case of the stories and chapters, if you want to avoid the 4th row in my example, then you should go with the first design, because absolutly nothing, in the example you gave me, is stopping anyone to insert a wrong row. How would you manage to stop it? And if you stop it, it will be just like the first design. Why do you absolutly want to stick with this design?

Comment: Ahh. I just wanted to know and clarify things in my head else i won't be able to completely move on from this.

So in this case, i should just pick the design which is inherently better at security? It's also much simpler and shorter to write the code for inserting just involving two tables.

Comment: Pick the design that is right for your model, it's not only about security. When you want to make a relationship, always think about the meaning of it. In this case: "How many chapters per story? How many stories per chapter?". One to many doens't mean you have only one row in a table and remember that a relationship must be read in the both sides. It may take time before you know exactly what you are doing with database modeling, but don't be afraid of making mistakes, you will learn from it. You should read some books and tutorials about it, it helps.